# Major Block Ciphers between DES and AES competitions

Tags: block-cipher, history

DES was announced as a standard in 1976. AES competition started in 1997 and Rijndael was selected as standard in 2000. What are major block ciphers and block cipher designs made/proposed from 1976 to 1997?

Answer (score 3):

[IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Data_Encryption_Algorithm#cite_note-7) and [CAST-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAST-128) (aka CAST5) first come to my mind as widely deployed/used ciphers. [Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)) and [TEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) are next. The first two (and to some degree the third) got support in PGP early on.

Update per [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/55582/555#comment123008_55584): [RC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC2), [RC5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5), and [GOST 28147-89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_(block_cipher)) (in the Eastern block) also have been widely used.

All 7 are 64-bit block ciphers; that's typical of the era, and made these block ciphers a painless substitute for DES and [3DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) (the dominant ciphers). They stood the test of time quite well, with no practical attack better than brute force by more than very few bits (except for GHOST, but when used with its full 256-bit key it remains safe enough). While TEA is involved in a notorious [incident](https://events.ccc.de/congress/2005/fahrplan/attachments/674-slides_xbox.pdf#page=77) where a game console misused it for hashing, that's hardly a problem attributable to TEA itself.

Note: I'd have included [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) if is was a block cipher; that used to be widespread in quite a few commercial applications.

Comment: PES (successor of IDEA) and FEAL also come to mind. Square (1997) was definitely important (origin of integral attacks). Skipjack is probably also relevant (but was classified until 1998). Same goes for GOST. Of course, the length of the list depends on what we will consider as "major". e.g. many designs succeeded Rijndael (including Square, 3-Way and BaseKing).

Comment: @Aleph: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Data_Encryption_Algorithm) says PES is an early version of IDEA. I've heard more about attacks than uses regarding FEAL.

Comment: RC4 may not be applicable, but [RC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC2) and [RC5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5) definitely are. RC2 was designed specifically to be used in Lotus Notes. On the Soviet side, [GOST 28147-89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_(block_cipher)) was pretty major. Merkle's [Khufu and Khafre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khufu_and_Khafre) are noteworthy as early software-friendly designs, but unclear what their actual impact was.

Comment: @fgrieu Should have been "predecessor" rather than "successor" (same for Square, 3-Way and BaseKing). I'd argue that being used isn't necessarily the only argument for importance.

Comment: I'd include 3DES in the list.